# android app LocalDate alternative for older API level

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building a calendar app and mostly in my code I use `LocalDate` to set my `RecyclerView` and some more functions.
I have a tablet that it's android version is 7.1.1, so it cant run anything in my code related to `LocalDate`.

I want to contest my self and make my app run to min SDK 16. Are there any alternatives for `LocalDate` for my code? I also use `Calendar` in my code but for my `RecyclerView` is almost the triple code to do same task. Any other suggestion would be apreciated.

Comment: There's [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which will both make most of `java.time` available in lower Android API Levels. I wouldn't rely on an outdated API if I didn't have to, it was supplanted for reason.

Comment: I will try give it a try

Comment: @deHaar Would you make an Answer of your Comment?

Comment: OK, I can do that ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have Java 8+ features available in lower Android version, you can use one of the following options:

- import the [ThreeTen Android Backport (ABP)](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)
- make use of [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

With (one of) these two, you can use nearly all of the classes and functions of `java.time` in Android API Levels < 26, including `LocalDate`.

Comment: It works fine for everything related to java.time . I have also functions for .sort and NotificationChannel Alarm. I saw in an other stack that this method should work for sort, streams too but, for some reason it doesnt work for me. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I'm not sure which functions you are talking about… Maybe ask another question with a brief description of the problem. The chance to get it solved here in the comments is pretty low.

Comment: Call requires API level 23 (current min is 16): android.app.AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle


Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): java.util.ArrayList#sort

these functions I mean

Comment: I think there's no backport for those things, the one concerning `java.time` was explicitly made due to java version differences. The `AlarmManager` is not used in plain Java, it is Android exclusive. I guess you have to check the API version in the code and only use this function when the API level of the calling device is actually supporting it. Or do some research, I bet you are not the first one having a problem like this in Android.