# android app AlarmManager and java.util.ArrayList#sort alternative for older API level

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building a calendar app and mostly in my code I use `ArrayList.sort` and `AlarmManager` to set my RecyclerView and some more functions.
I have a tablet that it's android version is 7.1.1, so it cant run anything in my code related to `ArrayList.sort` and `AlarmManager`.

I want to contest my self and make my app run to min SDK 16.I searched about Java 8+ API desugaring because I had a related problem with `LocalDate` `java.time`
[android app LocalDate alternative for older API level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76382104/11168157).

Unfortunately it doesn't work for `ArrayList.sort` and `AlarmManager`.

In `build.gradle` I made these changes

```
        multiDexEnabled true
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

    }
dependencies {

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'

}
```

and also

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false

}
```

Error I get:
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): java.util.ArrayList#sort

Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): android.app.NotificationManager#createNotificationChannel

Comment: `cant run anything in my code related to ArrayList.sort and AlarmManager` - what error does it shows, check/attach logs

Comment: I updated the question with the errors at the bottom

Comment: Use `List` interface instead of `arraylist` , it will work. Reason: [Api available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) - all I could see is sort method of List class is supported.

Comment: `createNotificationChannel` is only for android 8 and above. Notification Channel is not available for below api  in support libraries. You need to add version check for this - [Create Notification Channel](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels#CreateChannel)

Comment: Thank could you post these 2 comment as 1 answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `List` interface instead of `ArrayList` to use sort method in android desugaring.
Check the complete list of support api for Java8+ desugaring - [java8 desugaring support table](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

---

`createNotificationChannel` is only for android 8 and above. Notification Channel is not available for below api in support libraries. You need to add version check for this - [Create and manage notifications](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels#CreateChannel)